# How do I center a group of photos

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I'm trying to center the six photos below that are in the div "photos" inside the div "content" but I am unable to figure it out. Do I wrap them in another div? Any help would be great, as I'm still a novice (clearly).

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <h1>gage</h1>

<div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
   <div></div>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>

<div class="main-nav responsive-menu">
    <UL>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content"> 
    <div class="photos">
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <P>More stuff</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are inline elements so (all else being equal):

```
.photos {
    text-align: center;
}
```

From [the docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop):

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.

Comment: Thanks! I had .photos {display: inline;} in there, which was messing it up. Deleted and added text-align:center and all is right with the world. Now to fix my nonfunctioning hamburger menu.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **center** tag to center align your image.

```
<div class="content"> 
<div class="photos">
    <center>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
   </center>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `<center>` was deprecated in 1997. This is the wrong century to use it in.

Comment: I know it was deprecated but still an easy way for new people.